# What does this block of obfuscated JavaScript do? 

Tags: javascript

I've seen a block of JavaScript code, that return an alert message with 1 on page load. Here is the code

```
($=[$=[]][(__=!$+$)[_=-~-~-~$]+({}+$)[_/_]+
($$=($_=!''+$)[_/_]+$_[+$])])()[__[_/_]+__
[_+~$]+$_[_]+$$](_/_)
```

Can someone please explain what's going on here?